# I want to add the material design 3 serchview with the floatingbutton but it get problem can any one can solve this me

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In this code i will use an material design 3 serchview with the floatingbutton but it get problem when i click on the serchbar it will open the serchview but when serchview will open the floating button will not hidde and it will show in the open serview view pleas any one can solve this problem...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbqyz.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

        <!--        <FrameLayout-->
        <!--            android:id="@+id/coplanar_detached_side_sheet_container"-->
        <!--            style="@style/Widget.Material3.SideSheet.Detached"-->
        <!--            android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--            android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--            android:orientation="vertical"-->
        <!--            app:layout_behavior="@string/side_sheet_behavior" />-->

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:statusBarForeground="?attr/colorSurface">

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
                android:id="@+id/search_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                app:menu="@menu/profile"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/round_menu_24"
                />

            <com.google.android.material.progressindicator.LinearProgressIndicator
                android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
            android:id="@+id/search_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search_something"
            app:animateNavigationIcon="true"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/search_list"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>

        <!--        <FrameLayout-->
        <!--            android:id="@+id/standard_bottom_sheet"-->
        <!--            style="@style/Widget.Material3.BottomSheet"-->
        <!--            android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--            android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
        <!--            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">-->

        <!--            &lt;!&ndash; Drag handle for accessibility &ndash;&gt;-->
        <!--            <com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetDragHandleView-->
        <!--                android:id="@+id/drag_handle"-->
        <!--                android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />-->
        <!--        </FrameLayout>-->

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/floating_action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:contentDescription="TODO"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/round_person_add_alt_24"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription,HardcodedText" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/navigations" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i want to hide this floating action button form the serchview within the this xml or activity file..